# chrome extension doesn't load

Tags: google-chrome-extension

made my first chorme ext. and it works fine on old comp.
now with new one try to load unpacked ext. and it don't works at all. i see my ext popup ad bg.html but content script didn't loads at all, neiter images that shold be on target page.
other unpacked ext works fine. but mine refuse works( help me please!
`manifest.json`:

```
{
    "background_page": "bg.html",
    "name": "lardi trans",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icon_48.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon_48.png",
        "default_title": "Lardi Trans",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "http://lardi-trans.com/gruz/*",
        "http://lardi-trans.com/trans/*",
        "unlimitedStorage"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "http://lardi-trans.com/gruz/*",
            "http://lardi-trans.com/trans/*"
        ],
        "css": ["extent_styles.css"],
        "js": ["jq.js", "script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```

screenshots of page where ext should be i mark place where must appears my form
[console shot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28374703/ext1.PNG)
and other ext scripts loads like this ! [screenshot2](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28374703/ext_script.png) (5 times same script? WTF??) but anyway i can't see my ext script.js (why it din't loads?)

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Does any error occur? (Content script errors are reported on the page where they're active, background script errors can be made visible via `chrome://extensions/` -> <YOUR EXTENSION NAME> -> `bg.html` (in Developer mode).

Comment: unfortunatly scripts didn't loads( and course errors can't appears.

Comment: I can't do anything with such a vague description... Write a proper bug report.

Comment: content scripts and other ext files like content_css.css not injekted on target page at all. but i can see background page and popup exp supposed to add some html form to provide some additional functionality for site lardi-trans.com main feature is searching for loads and trow the notification about finded p.s. sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to give the link of css to manifest.json file. Just, call it in bg.html

My manifest.json file

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "version": "2.0",
  "description": "Example.com Description",
  "icons": { "16":"Images/Example/16x16.png", "32":"Images/Example/32x32.png", "48": "Images/Example/48x48.png", "64": "Images/Example/64x64.png", "128": "Images/Example/128x128.png" },

  "app": 
  {
        "default_icon": "../Images/Example/icon.png",
        "launch": 
        {
            "local_path": "Pages/Index.html"
        }
  },

  "permissions": [ "http://www.Example.com/", 
                   "http://*.Example.com/", 
                   "https://www.Example.com/",
                   "https://*.Example.com/",
                   "unlimitedStorage",
                   "tabs",
                   "notifications"
                   ],
  "options_page": "Pages/Options.html",
  "background_page": "Pages/Background.html"
}
```

If that answer helped you, please mark it as an answer...

If you are still taking errors, please ask them to bottom of that answer.

Best Regards.

**EDIT**:

*View errors - Steps;*

Click your extension button to open it.

Open the debug window in Google Chrome with F12 key.

Click "Console" tab page.

Take a screenshot of it, and post the picture in your question.

With that way everybody can help you =)

EDIT 2:

ok your question seems looking littlebit different now.

Here is algorithm;

Download the site sourcecode of target webpage with jquery,
Insert your css line in head tag with json,
Store new source code in localStorage( html5 )
When it's done, refresh the page with js, and read new source code from localStorage
And show it in html.

Comment: but i need to inject my css styles to target page (lardi-trans.com) and it was working untill i try to install on new comp

Comment: it's prety tricky end i will try it, but main problem that my extention script.js not loads( and i can't get why.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone interests, problem solved, by some reason in manifest add unprop whitespases `"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://lardi-trans.com/gruz/*","http://lardi-trans.com/trans/*"],`
this works!))